# Super+space disables the Activities overview shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, 20.04, activities-overview

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04. As far as I can tell, there seems to be at least 3 shortcuts to access the Activities menu: <kbd>Super</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

I also tend to switch between "en-us" and "pt" keyboard layouts often with the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> shortcut.

The problem is, when I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to switch to the Portuguese layout, the <kbd>Super</kbd> shortcut stops working. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> still work though, but they're not as handy.

When I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> again to switch back to en-us, the <kbd>Super</kbd> shortcut starts working again.

Any idea why this might be happening?
I suspect something else also has <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> registered as a shortcut for a different purpose, but I don't know where to look.